# Redirect Old url with params using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm setting up my site, but I have old links, we are using SEO-friendly links now.
For example, old users were www.mysite.com/view_member.php?id=X

Now, our links are www.mysite.com/profile/X

I wanted to know how to use the .htaccess

I tried:

```
RedirectMatch ^/view_member.php?id=(.*) profile/$1 [R]
```

But had no luck.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Added current .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|user_guide|files|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]


<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^profile/(.+)$ view_member.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it got my Internal Server Error.

I edited my main post t show my current .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ view_member.php?id=$1
```